# Tweet not creating in django twitter clone

Tags: python, django

I am just trying to build  a simple twitter clone using django. To create a new tweet, a user has to choose an image and type some text. So i do just that, and when I click on the create tweet button, I get a form error that says "The image field is required".
I don't understand why this happens. Here is a screenshot of that error:

[image]

I don't even get ant error message. Here is my `CreateTweet` view function:

```
class CreateTweetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Tweet 
    fields = ('image','tweet')
    template_name = 'twitter/create_tweet.html'

    def form_valid(self):
        new_tweet = form.save(commit=False)
        new_tweet.author = self.request.user
        new_tweet.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

What is the problem here?

EDIT:

1. I have chosen an image, and upon form submission, I get this error
2. In the media folder, I don't see the uploaded image

Comment: Image field is a required field. In html template, it will be required field. So, you have to choose an image to submit the form without error

Comment: I have chosen an image, still I am getting this error

Comment: In the screenshot it says "No file chosen".

Comment: That is the problem. I choose an image, and i get this weird error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by using multipart form data in your template.
Some thing like this,

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```